# Как правильно обрабатывать нажатие на один элемент галереи?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть небольшая простая галерея, нажимаешь на ссылку меняется картинка, **но** дело в том, что таких блоков множество и при нажатии на ссылку в одном блоке смена происходит во всех остальных.

```
<p>
    <p class='bigfoto'><a href="#"><img src="img/toy2.jpg"></a></p>
    <ul class='smallfoto'>
        <li><a href='img/toy2-g.jpg'><img src='img/round-color/green.png'></a></li>
        <li><a href='img/toy2-b.png'><img src='img/round-color/b.png'></a></li>
        <li><a href='img/toy2.jpg'><img src='img/round-color/red.png'></a></li>
    </ul>
</p>

<script>
$(document)
         .ready(function () {
             var small = $(".smallfoto li img"),
                 big = $(".bigfoto img");
             small.each(function (i, el) {
             var next = i + 1 == small.size() ? 0 : i + 1;
             $(el)
                     .click(
                         function (event) {
                             event.preventDefault();
                             if(big.data("next") == next) return;
                             big.fadeTo(00, 0.1, function () {
                                 big.attr({
                                     "src": $(el)
                                         .parent()
                                         .attr("href")
                                 })
                                     .data({
                                         "next": next
                                     });
                             });
                             big.fadeTo(800, 1);
                         }
                 )
             });
             big.data({
                 "next": 1
             })
                 .click(function (event) {
                     small.eq($(this)
                         .data("next"))
                         .click()
                 })
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что изменилось?

Оборачиваем в `$('.gallery').each(function() {`. Соответственно HTML тоже поменялся.

`small` и `big` переменные добавлено `,this`, тем самым мы указываем на `.gallery`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.gallery').each(function() {


    var small = $(".smallfoto li img", this),
      big = $(".bigfoto img", this);

    small.each(function(i, el) {
      var next = i + 1 == small.size() ? 0 : i + 1;
      $(el)
        .click(
          function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (big.data("next") == next) return;
            big.fadeTo(00, 0.1, function() {
              big.attr({
                  "src": $(el)
                    .parent()
                    .attr("href")
                })
                .data({
                  "next": next
                });
            });
            big.fadeTo(800, 1);
          }
        )
    });
    big.data({
        "next": 1
      })
      .click(function(event) {
        small.eq($(this)
            .data("next"))
          .click()
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <p class='bigfoto'>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/toy2.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
  <ul class='smallfoto'>
    <li>
      <a href='img/toy2-g.jpg'>
        <img src='img/round-color/green.png'>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='img/toy2-b.png'>
        <img src='img/round-color/b.png'>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='img/toy2.jpg'>
        <img src='img/round-color/red.png'>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```